# How to use entityQuery with custom field type?

Tags: entities, 9

I am working on building a query for nodes that have a few custom fields (field types). The fields are custom build in a custom module with a custom schema. When I execute the query:

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'place');
 $query->condition('my_custom_field', '', '<>');
```

It fails with a message indicating that:
`node__my_custom_field.my_custom_field_value` does not exist (NOT found). This is correct the table has a custom schema for this field `_value` does not exist:

```
 drush sqlq "describe node__my_custom_field"

bundle  varchar(128)    NO  MUL     
deleted tinyint(4)  NO  PRI 0   
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    
revision_id int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL NULL    
langcode    varchar(32) NO  PRI     
delta   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    
my_custom_field_title   text    YES     NULL    
my_custom_field_description text    YES     NULL
```

How do I make my entity field query work with this field custom schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your custom field type has `title` and `description` columns rather than `value` (the default Drupal assumes if you don't tell it otherwise).

You can specify the field column to use with `.` notation like this:

```
$query->condition('my_custom_field.title', '', '<>');
$query->condition('my_custom_field.description', '', '<>');
```

If you want the system to consider, for example, the `title` property as the default instead of `value`, you can implement [`FieldItemBase::mainPropertyName()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemBase.php/function/FieldItemBase%3A%3AmainPropertyName/9.2.x) in your field class:

```
public static function mainPropertyName() {
  return 'title';
}
```

That would make your original line work for the `title` column:

```
$query->condition('my_custom_field', '', '<>');
```

Comment: Thanks .. I should have figured this one ..